# Detete user from firebase authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4, angular8

> Delete a user from Firebase Authentication using Angular and When the user's is not Logged In

Is there a way I can get a specific user account from firebase and then delete it?

Comment: Hello, you should add more details. Who should delete the user? An admin user? "When the user's is not Logged In" -> what do you exactly mean? Do you need to use a presence system?

Comment: "When the user's is not Logged In

Answer (score 2):

When using the client-side SDKs for Firebase Authentication, you can only delete the user account that is currently signed in. Anything else would be a huge security risk, as it would allow users of your app to delete each other's account.

The Admin SDKs for Firebase Authentication are designed to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. Because they run in a trusted environment, they can perform certain operations that the client-side SDKs can't perform. Such as for example: deleting user accounts by simply knowing their UID.

Here's an example of deleting a user from Node.js:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid);
```

For more information and examples in the other supported languages, see the documentation for [deleting a user with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).